# React: style all elements with inline styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make all of my elements border-box. I want to do this:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

How is that possible to do in with React's inline styles? I don't want to write that rule in each component...

Comment: Why can't you use single CSS rule for that? Having the same rule in every React component seems like an overhead

Comment: don't abuse inline styles

Comment: I agree that this seems silly. But if you DID want to do it then you'd probably pass some kind of "global" style object down through props to each component, and merge it with the individual components' styles there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ill-advised since CSS will be much more efficient, manageable, and flexible. But if you REALLY wanted to have global inline React styles, I might do it like this:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    globalStyle: {
        boxSizing: "border-box"
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent globalStyle={this.globalStyle} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    style: {
        border: "1px solid black"
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={Object.assign({}, this.props.globalStyle, this.style)}></div>
        );
    }
});
```

Basically pass global style down to components as props and have them incorporate it there.

Note that `Object.assign()`'s first parameter is a new empty object (so that we don't accidentally mutate our others) and that `this.style` comes last (so that it overrides any global styles.)

If you wanted the global style to change, you'd do it with React's component `state` instead and use `getInitialState` etc. I suppose that might actually be the only reason you'd *want* to do it this way.